# ActiveRecord - include nested associations instead of just id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a rails api with two ActiveRecords, User and Organization.  Organization has_many users and User belongs_to Organization.  When I find a user, by their email, I automatically get the organization_id as part of the record.  When I render the json for the response, right now I am calling `user.as_json(include: :organization)` which does include the organization.  However, this is what I get:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "My Name",
  "organization_id": 1,
  "organization": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "My Organization"
  }
}
```

How can I structure my query to return this?

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "My Name",
  "organization": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "My Organization"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user.as_json(include: :organization, except: [:organization_id])`

Comment: Well, that was remarkably easy.  Thank you!